# 0xdbe doesn't display tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use 0xDBE and connect it to my testing MS SQL Server database.

When I connect to it 0xDBE doesn't display schemas names but shows only users in visual tree.

There is a view in 0xDBE:

[image: 0xDBE screenshot]

And the same database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

[image: SSMS screenshot]

There are no errors in the console.

Comment: What is 0xDBE? Have you contacted their support team?

Comment: It's an IDE from JetBrains that is still in beta apparently https://www.jetbrains.com/dbe/

Comment: Which JDBC driver and version are you using? jTDS or the Microsoft driver?

Comment: that is not a list of users, that is a list of schemas. for example, expand dbo, and you will get a list of objects in the dbo schema

Comment: @BobKlimes Under dbo schema I have only 5 tables. Is it possible to display tables inside this dbo as Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (i.e. I need to display data inside inner01_MSCRM). Or I'm using wrong tool for it?

Comment: If you only see 5 databases, you are probably connected to master (four `spt_` tables and a replications option table). Try changing your database context to a user database (sorry, I don't use 0xDBE so I can't give explicit advice on how to do that).

Comment: I've found an answer about db connection.
I needed to add additional setting in addition to "Host" in DB Url     jdbc:sqlserver://sql1.crmtest1.sitecore.net;databaseName=inner01_MSCRM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 11/4/15, there is an update to the SQL Server provider that clears up creating the data source. You may need to refresh the data source to actually list the tables.